# Prevent af:fileDownloadActionListener action event

Tags: jsf-2, download, oracle-adf, phaselistener

## Background

Using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3 to create a report download button using `fileDownloadActionListener` as follows:

```
<af:commandButton text="Run Report" id="submitReport">
  <af:fileDownloadActionListener method="#{reportBean.run}"/>
</af:commandButton>
```

At the top of this JSF page is the following:

```
<f:view afterPhase="#{validationBean.afterPhase}" ...>
  ...
    <af:form id="f1">
      <f:event listener="#{validationBean.postValidate}" type="postValidate"/>
```

The idea is that the Validation Bean can capture any validation problems as follows:

```
public void afterPhase(javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent phaseEvent) {
  if (phaseEvent.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
    FacesContext context = phaseEvent.getFacesContext();
    FacesMessage.Severity severity = context.getMaximumSeverity();

    if (isSevereError(severity)) {
      context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(ERROR_FLAG_NAME, true);
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected. When the user presses the button, but the form has an error, the `validationError` session variable is set to `true`. This should allow the framework to prevent the report from being generated if the form parameters have errors.

## Problem

The `validationError` session variable is used by the report bean's run method as follows:

```
  public void run(FacesContext facesContext, OutputStream outputStream) {
    Object error = facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get( ERROR_FLAG_NAME );

    if( error != null && error != Boolean.TRUE ) {
      Report report = null;

      try {
        report = getReport();
        report.setOutputStream(outputStream);
        configure(report.getParameters());
        report.run();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        if (report != null && facesContext != null) {
          report.publish(e);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      facesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove( ERROR_FLAG_NAME );
      facesContext.renderResponse();
    }
  }
```

When there is a validation error in the page, the `facesContext.renderResponse();` code is executed, but the resulting web page is blank. No exceptions are logged. No errors are generated.

## Question

One way to avoid this situation uses a hidden button, custom Java, and some JavaScript, as described on the following pages:

- http://jobinesh.blogspot.ca/2010/01/customizing-execution-of-to-validate.html
- http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/validate-data-before-export-via-afexportcollectionactionlistener-or-affiledownloadactionlistener/

However, that mechanism is complicated. The solution I have in mind will work if the page can be rendered as usual.

How do you force the page to be rendered after the `af:fileDownloadActionListener` event has fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank Nimphius [said](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10827427):

> using a hidden button is the only option you have available today. I
>   will file an ER that raises an event for the fileDownload listener
>   (sort of a pre-download) that should allow you to cancel it by calling
>   Render Response. As said, this doesn't exist yet and the hidden button
>   is the option you have available (note that the file download tag is a
>   client behavior tag and not a full UI component, which is why there is
>   no way yet to interrupt execution.